# HTML "if" statement background toggle

Tags: javascript, html, css, if-statement, togglebutton

I'm new to learning CSS/HTML and i've been working a bit on trying to recreate the windows 98 vibe. However, one thing I've had a lot of trouble with specifically is trying to recreate the "start" button with a simple toggle script.

You can see an example of the current script i'm using here; https://thealonic.tumblr.com/ most of the work is my own work with some scraps of css from the old theme I was using along with win98.css

I've looked around a bit and tried around 4-5 solutions with no luck over the course of a couple hours, but none seemed to be helping me making any progress so I just tried to use more bare bones solutions by just using if statements.

```
<head>
<style>
   .start_button {
      float: left; background-image: url(https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/630047188520665121/785903172115234846/unknown.png);
      height: 22px; width: 54px; margin-left: 2px; margin-top: 2px; z-index: 3; background-repeat:no-repeat;}
</style>
</head>
```

```
<body class="win98>
   <div class="start_button" id="start_button" onclick="startpress()"></div>
   <script>
      function startpress() {
      if (document.getElementById("start_button").style.backgroundImage !== "url('https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/630047188520665121/785903300292902982/unknown.png')") {
      document.getElementById("start_button").style.backgroundImage = "url('https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/630047188520665121/785903300292902982/unknown.png')" } else {
      document.getElementById("start_button").style.backgroundImage = "url('https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/630047188520665121/785903172115234846/unknown.png')"}}
   </script>
</body>
```

This "almost" gets the job done but, the trouble I'm having is that the button recognises the press, and then it says down, even with such a simple if statement like this. I've seen this solution work for pretty much the exact same usecase but I don't understand why this doesn't quite work. Is there just something about html scripts specifically I don't quite understand?

Anyway, thanks for any help I get in advance and sorry if this has been asked before, but a quick search didn't get anything like this specifically as I'm not entirely sure if the cause is just the way I'm addressing the background image.

Comment: so mousedown and mouseup.... Just toggle a class, no reason to set styles directly

Comment: @teemu, yeah you're correct. I'll adjust the post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the solution to the problem i finally got around to solving.

So for the taskbar I have this, which just toggles between true and false alongside addressing the window titlebar and the taskbar.

```
function tumblrtoggle() { pyroButtonOpen = true; 
                        if (tumblrButtonOpen == false) { inactiveall(); tumblrButtonOpen = true;
                            document.getElementById("post").style.zIndex = (currentno = currentno + 1); currentno = currentno + 1;
                            document.getElementById("postwindow").style.backgroundImage = "url('https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/630047188520665121/791328235451318342/title-bar_postheaderinactive.png')";
                            document.getElementById("taskapp1").style.backgroundImage = "url('https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/630047188520665121/789420847604564008/Taskbar_application1.png')";
                        } else if (pyroButtonOpen == true){ inactiveall(); tumblrButtonOpen = false;
                            document.getElementById("postwindow").style.backgroundImage = "url('https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/630047188520665121/791321110750298162/title-bar_postheader.png')";
                            document.getElementById("taskapp1").style.backgroundImage = "url('https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/630047188520665121/789416557692452884/Taskbar_application.png')";}}
```

And having this else where in the html so you don't have to keep calling "true" to each window if you have multiple.

```
function inactiveall() { 
                tumblrButtonOpen = true;
                document.getElementById("postwindow").style.backgroundImage = "url('https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/630047188520665121/791328235451318342/title-bar_postheaderinactive.png')";
                document.getElementById("taskapp1").style.backgroundImage = "url('https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/630047188520665121/789420847604564008/Taskbar_application1.png')";
}
```

Then to actually create the script for the window for when the window is clicked onto;

```
function tumblractive() { tumblrButtonOpen = false;
                document.getElementById("post").style.zIndex = (currentno = currentno + 1); currentno = currentno + 1;
                document.getElementById("postwindow").style.backgroundImage = "url('https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/630047188520665121/791321110750298162/title-bar_postheader.png')"; 
                document.getElementById("taskapp1").style.backgroundImage = "url('https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/630047188520665121/789416557692452884/Taskbar_application.png')";
}
```

Example is used here; https://thealonic.tumblr.com/ (all the windows use the same scripts with different names and alterations for different functionability)

Answer (score 0):

The problem in your code is that the condition inside the if statement doesn't change every time you click the button. You need some kind of toggle that changes at every click. You can try something like this:

```
  const startButton = document.getElementById("start_button");
  let startButtonOpen = false;
  function startpress() {
    startButtonOpen = !startButtonOpen;
    if (startButtonOpen) {
      startButton.style.backgroundImage = "url('https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/630047188520665121/785903300292902982/unknown.png')";
    } else {
      startButton.style.backgroundImage = "url('https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/630047188520665121/785903172115234846/unknown.png')";
    }
  }
```

Comment: This didn't work originally, but doing a small tweak and changing the const into a var seemed to work. But for some reason, ONLY worked with my original if statement without the "else" part. Why? I have no diea.
Either way, the solution I now have is jank has hell but I'l probably get around to making it more clean. Thanks a LOT for making my hours of time wasted on solving this worth while! <3

Answer (score 0):

You probably need a Eval or something like that in the if.
But i would go with something more simple

var startmode=true

If (startmode)

{

startmode=false

document.getElementById("start_button").style.backgroundImage = "url('https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/630047188520665121/785903300292902982/unknown.png')"

}

else

{

startmode=true

document.getElementById("start_button").style.backgroundImage = "url('https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/630047188520665121/785903172115234846/unknown.png')"

}